# My memcpy function prints the src twice unexpectedly

Tags: c, memcpy

https://onlinegdb.com/B1OmLVB6D

I am not sure why the src variable prints out twice after running memcpyByByte function.

```
int memcpyByByte(void* src, void* dest, size_t len) {
    char* srcC = (char*)src;
    char* destC = (char*)dest;
    
    for(int i = 0; i< len; i++){
        *(destC+i) = *(srcC+i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char a[10] = "1234567890";
    char b[10] = "6b";

    memcpyByByte(&a, &b, sizeof(a));

    printf("src:  %s\n", a);
    printf("dest: %s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a isn't big enough for the null teminator, so the program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's either undefined behavior for reading from invalid memory address, or undefined behavior for writing into invalid memory address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C-strings have an implied terminating byte of value 0 (NULL) at the end.
The size of string `"1234567890"` is 11, not 10.

Assigning it to 10-element long array will cause the terminator to be lost. Thus `printf()` will continue scanning the memory after `a`, likely printing content of `b`.

Just change size of `a` and `b` to `11`. Or let the compiler determine the size:

```
char a[] = "1234567890";
char b[sizeof a] = "6g";
```

Comment: And how exactly would copying 11 (or even 10) characters into a memory block of only 3 characters be a deterministic operation?

Comment: @goodvibration: `sizeof b` is 10, not 3, but it's still too small to hold 11 bytes.